# Button tap issue while back navigation

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin forms application, there are two pages Page 1 and Page 2.
When clicking a button in Page 1 navigation occurs from Page 1 to Page 2.
My problem is while coming back from Page 2 to Page 1 the button is not responding on the first click and it will respond on the second click. It occurs continuously. Is it a focus issue. Please help me.

Following is the rough design of my UI

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>  
                <Image   Source="selectuser.png" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="Select User" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Style="{StaticResource ItemLabelStyle}" WidthRequest="95"/> 
                <Button Grid.RowSpan="2" BackgroundColor="Transparent"  Command="{Binding SelecUserCommand}" />
            </Grid>
```

Comment: Please provide some code how you set the button otherwise it's almost impossible to help.

Comment: Added a rough design.

Comment: I don't think it is connected to focus. You need to debug this. Try to put a breakpoint inside the getter of SelecUserCommand property in your binding context class. Do you get there when the button is irresponsive? If yes than the problem is inside the command. If no than it's probably broken binding context. You'll need to override onbindingcontextchanged member and check the command property of the button. Is it null? You could give Name property to button to make the debugging easier - this will create member variable. And another guess - misspelled SelecUserCommand (instead of Select)?